# roo 1.1.5 sample gwtNoEntities fails to load

Tags: gwt, spring-roo, gwt-mvp

I'm building roo samples gwtNoEntities, I'm getting following failure log. Could any one fixed this problem. please let me know.

`[ERROR] ScaffoldMobileApp.java:[3,0] packag
e com.springsource.foo.client.managed.activity does not exist
[ERROR] ScaffoldMobileApp.java:[5,45] packa
ge com.springsource.foo.client.managed.ui does not exist`

Comment: ROO's GWT support always fail for me (sooner or later). Tried several versions and gave up.

Answer (score 0):

gwtNoEntities is as simple as:

```
project --topLevelPackage com.springsource.foo
persistence setup --provider DATANUCLEUS --database HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY 
gwt setup
```

The error indicates that there are some packages missing, these packages are normally generated by the gwt setup command. Rerun gwt setup in the roo shell or start a new project (new directory) and type the three commands.

Answer (score 0):

Running this worked for me

```
dependency add --groupId com.google.appengine --artifactId appengine-api-1.0-sdk --version 1.4.0
```